# loading the csv file via https, Cypher error

Tags: cypher

I'm trying to run the code below with respect to load the csv file via https. But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Invalid input 'C': expected whitespace, comment or end of input (line 2, column 1) 
"CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productName);"
 ^
```

Can someone help me to correct it??

```
// tag::indexes[]
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productName);
CREATE INDEX ON :Category(categoryID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Employee(employeeID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Supplier(supplierID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Customer(customerID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Customer(customerName);
// end::indexes[]

// Create customers
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName, customerID: row.CustomerID, fax: row.Fax, phone: row.Phone});
// Create products
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/products.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Product {productName: row.ProductName, productID: row.ProductID, unitPrice: toFloat(row.UnitPrice)});

// Create suppliers
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/suppliers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Supplier {companyName: row.CompanyName, supplierID: row.SupplierID});

// Create employees
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/employees.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Employee {employeeID:row.EmployeeID,  firstName: row.FirstName, lastName: row.LastName, title: row.Title});

// Create categories
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/categories.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Category {categoryID: row.CategoryID, categoryName: row.CategoryName, description: row.Description});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://github.com/stevetmat/CSV-Files/blob/master/orders.csv" AS row
MERGE (order:Order {orderID: row.OrderID}) ON CREATE SET order.shipName =  row.ShipName;
```

Comment: How are you running this?  Via neo4j-shell?

Comment: No, I actually run this via Neo4j (http://localhost:7474/browser/)" Any idea?

Comment: You can only run one query at a time via that browser.  You're getting a syntax error on the second one because you're giving it way too much.  Run them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are trying to run this in one transaction/procedure? When creating indexes you need to execute lines individually.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it. Thanks